# KeyBoard Navigation for menu using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-navigation

I am trying to add keyboard navigation   to Menu(ul li based
) , i have bound the keydown event to  menu (or should i bind keydown to the document ?)

the handler function used  is given below

```
 KeyDown: function(e) {        

    var toFocus = false;


                  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
         toFocus = $((e.target/* li */).next()[0]);
      }
                          if (e.keyCode == 40) {
         toFocus = $((e.target).next()[1]);
      }
    if (toFocus) {
        $(e.target).attr('tabIndex', '-1');
        $(toFocus).attr('tabIndex', '0');
        toFocus.focus();
        return false;
        }
        }
```

here i get **e.target as html** instead of li  ?

can u suggest any other way to add keyboard navigation ?

Comment: Answer on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308378/how-to-navigate-with-keyboard-through-ul-li-element/7320614#7320614). (with a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7MSN/118/))

Answer (score 1):

I just wonder if, instead of doing this by your self, why not using an already existing plugin?

> [jQuery Keyboard Navigation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/keynav/)

demo [page here](http://amountaintop.com/jquery-keyboard-navigation-plugin)

> **my demo**: just to add a [demo page](http://balexandre.com/jquery/keynav/) of an example

Comment: I the plugin is complex , all i need is to set focus to my menu , and get the e.target to return the current menu item

Comment: you're kidding right? complex? mate... please look at my own example and tell me what complex is this all about! :-)

Comment: Thanx for the demo , btw i dint mean the usage of the plugin was complex , i ment the plugin complex calculations about x y positions n stuffs , the code i mentioned above was working only problem with it was it returned html as event.target , i just need to find the current li which has the focus

Comment: all those lines of code you do in a cleaner manner and it's much better for future updates than look at your code ;) - with one line of code you do everything in the navigation (the init line) the rest is just animations to show you some nice effect.

Comment: the bottom line is, why trying to re-invent the wheel? Code Reuse is what we all should do in the first place as developers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use custom attribute to hold the tabid for up and down.

```
...KeyDown: function(e) {
    var Direction;
    if (e.keyCode == 38)
         Direction = "toUp";
    else Direction = "toDown";

    var Focus = $("li[tabid=\""$(e.target.id).attr(Direction)"\"]");
    Focus.focus();
}

---

<li ... tabid="1" toUp="-1" toDown= "2" />
<li ... tabid="2" toUp= "1" toDown= "3" />
<li ... tabid="3" toUp= "2" toDown= "4" />
<li ... tabid="4" toUp= "3" toDown="-1" />
```

The above code is just to show the idea, it is late now and I didn't have time to test it. So please don't vote me down for not working.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="target-box" >
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="selected">Hello</li>
        <li>World</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('focus','#target-box', function() {
    var target_box = $(this);

    $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {

        if(e.which == 38){ // up arrow
            var selected_item = $('.selected');
            if(typeof selected_item.prev()[0] !== 'undefined') {
                selected_item.prev().addClass('selected');
                selected_item.removeClass('selected');
            }
        } else if (e.which == 40) { // down arrow
            var selected_item = $('.selected');
            if (typeof selected_item.next()[0] !== 'undefined') {
                selected_item.next().addClass('selected');
                selected_item.removeClass('selected');
            }
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
            target_box.val($('.selected').html());
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.selected {
    width : 50px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```