# How to navigate with keyboard through <ul> <li> element

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, contextmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KeyBoard Navigation for menu using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409214/keyboard-navigation-for-menu-using-jquery)

I created a menu using `<ul> <li>` tags and showing it to the user when he presses `Enter` key in the textbox. He can select items of the menu (navigate in menu) using mouse but I want also to allow him to select items from that menu using up/dow buttons of the keyboard for example.

Is it any way to do that using jQuery or CSS?

My menu has following structure:

```
<div class="services">
  <div class="items">
    <ul>                           
        <li class="mail-icon"><a href="#" id="mail"><?php echo $langmsg['mail']; ?></a></li>
        <li class="forum-icon"><a href="#" id="forum"><?php echo $langmsg['forum']; ?></a></li>
        <li class="chat-icon"><a href="#" id="chat"><?php echo $langmsg['chat']; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: `<li>` element has a background image also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409214/keyboard-navigation-for-menu-using-jquery

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7MSN/118/)

Here is how to handle circular selection:

```
if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up
    var selected = $(".selected");
    $(".services li").removeClass("selected");

    // if there is no element before the selected one, we select the last one
    if (selected.prev().length == 0) {
        selected.siblings().last().addClass("selected");
    } else { // otherwise we just select the next one
        selected.prev().addClass("selected");
    }
}
```

css:

```
.services li.selected {
    background-color: grey;   
}
```

Comment: didn't use your code in full, but helped me a lot. thanks :)

Comment: it won't work if we have scroll bar. But overall a good example

Answer (score 3):

It's already possible, just with HTML, with "tab" key, then "Enter" key . You can double your CSS style `a:hover` by a `a:focus`, which will highlight this possibility =)