# Accessibility for custom dropdown button

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

Hi I need add keyboard navigation and accessibility to my custom dropdown button. Do you have any ideas? I thought about using aria?

```
<div class="dropdown-select">
  <input type="hidden" name="select_offer" class="dropdown-select--value" />
  <button class="dropdown-select--btn"> Lorem ipsum
    <span class="sr-only">(rozwiń listę)</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="opl-dropdown-select--list">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-option="value1">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-option="value2">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-option="value3">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Mozilla Foundation has described a technique for custom listbox elements: [Using the listbox role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_listbox_role) which implies multiple considerations :

- giving the `listbox` role to the element
- giving the `option` role on the different choices
- managing focus of the different elements for keyboard accessibility
- using `aria-activedescendant` for current focused element
- using `aria-selected` for current selected element

WCAG has full working examples in the page [Listbox examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/listbox/listbox.html) but this page is still under development.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a focus on div will be a problem. tabindex is not a valid attribute which can be applied to divs in HTML < 5.

It must have some element link a, textarea, button, input, object, select.

So, we implemented in a way similar to

[fiddle in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308378/how-to-navigate-with-keyboard-through-ul-li-element)

We put the text box inside a div

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this:

```
<div class="dropdown-select" role="menubar">
  <input type="hidden" name="select_offer" class="dropdown-select--value" />
  <button id="custom-dropdown" class="dropdown-select--btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Lorem ipsum
    <span class="sr-only">(rozwiń listę)</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="opl-dropdown-select--list" aria-label="submenu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="custom-dropdown">
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" data-option="value1">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" data-option="value2">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" data-option="value3">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The use of the `aria-expanded` attribute is really ideal, but if used, it would need to correctly display a value of true/false respectively as the element is expanded and collapsed.