# How to make bootstrap button dropdown menu selectable by keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap button dropdown: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

When i select a button dropdown, i would like to use keyboard up/down to navigate between menu items and press enter to select one, just like http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409214/keyboard-navigation-for-menu-using-jquery

Answer (score 22):

**Bootstrap has native support for keyboard navigation.**

Just add ***role="menu"*** to your ***dropdown-menu***

Here is an example, just save as .html and take a test

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default">1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">3</button>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu</button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li> <a href="#">one</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">two</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">three</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/damphat/WJS9p/

Comment: Keep in mind though, that whatever you give `role="menu"` needs to be able to receive focus. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1600194/601386. Only elements that can receive focus can bind to keyboard events.

Answer (score 9):

Possible reasons that this may not work in some cases:

- Because you use a `<div>` or a `<span>` for `.dropdown-toggle`. Make it a `<button>` and it will work. Strange enough, not even this kind of element works: `span.btn.btn-default`.
- Make sure your `<a>` element inside each `<li>` have an attribute of `href="#"` or `href=""` or generally has the attribute defined.
- Make sure you have the `role="menu"` on the `.dropdown-menu` element.